# Pushing Navigation Controller From Other Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Data Manager class that handles some JSON activities. When one action is completed, I want to push to the Navigation controller.

The FirstViewController calls a function on the DataManager Class

***DataManager Class***

```
class func extract_json(data:NSData) -> Bool {
    //Success
    FirstViewController().pushToValueView()
}
```

***FirstViewController Class***

```
func pushToValueView() {
    println("Push to Value View")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(ValueViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

In this example, `println()` is called but no push occurs. If I call `pushToValueView()` within FirstViewController e.g. `self.pushToValueView()` (For debug purposes), a push does occur.

Comment: You are instantiating a new instance of FirstViewController rather than referring to the instance that is already in use and in the navigation hierarchy. This is poor design anyway. You should supply a completion closure to `extract_json` that can perform the push in the context of the view controller class

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how can I call FirstViewController, the one that called DataManager in the first place?

Comment: When FirstViewController instance calls the DataManager method have it pass a completion closure to that method. When the DataManager method subsequently executes the closure then it runs in Yhe FirstViewController instance

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'll go away and research but if you had a link or two for an example, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this function on an existing instance of FirstViewController.
I think that in this example you try to push view controller to FirstViewController which is deallocated after exiting the method scope. That is why view controller doesn't appear

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I do not know how to do this in Swift (The same pattern is operational in my Obj-C version) FirstViewController calls the DataManager functions, how do I get them to call the calling FirstViewController successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap the optional. Edit: You shouldn't call your vc from a model class btw, thats bad MVC, I'd use an observers rather and get notified when the closure is complete

```
if let nav = self.navigationController {
     println("Push to Value View")
     nav.pushViewController(ValueViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer. how adding observer to listen to the completion of the closure

Comment: I maybe able to help if you can put the complete code

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `extract_json` function so that it accepts a closure to be executed once the data has been extracted.  The closure will contain the code to push the new view controller and it will execute in the context of the calling rather than called object:

In DataManager.swift -

```
func extractJSON(data:NSData, completion:() -> Void) {

   //Do whatever

    completion()

}
```

In FirstViewController.swift -

```
func getDataAndSegue() {

    extractJSON(someData, completion:{
             navigationController?.pushViewController(ValueViewController(), animated: true)
        }
    )
}
```